# Merging data sets with 2 different variables

Tags: merge, sas

This is my second day with SAS, I'm trying to merge VEKP and LIPS where VEKP has variable VPOBJKEY and LIPS has variable VBELN. VPOBJKEY and VBELN have the same data. I've searched the forum and found that I can rename them. Here is what I got so far but still cant get to the bottom. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
DATA TYPE (KEEP= EXIDV VHILM VPOBJKEY);
SET HD.VEKP;
WHERE VHILM = "H3";
RUN;

DATA MATERIAL (RENAME=(VBELN=VPOBJKEY)KEEP= VBELN MATNR);
SET HD.LIPS;
RUN;

DATA COMBINED;
MERGE MATERIAL (IN=INA)
TYPE (IN=INB);
BY VBELN;
IF INA AND INB THEN OUTPUT COMBINED;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I believe I figured it out.

```
DATA TYPE (KEEP= EXIDV VHILM VPOBJKEY);
SET HD.VEKP;
WHERE VHILM = "H3";
RUN;
PROC SORT DATA=TYPE; BY VPOBJKEY; RUN;

DATA MATERIAL (RENAME=(VBELN=VPOBJKEY)KEEP= VBELN MATNR);
SET HD.LIPS;
RUN;
PROC SORT DATA= MATERIAL; BY VPOBJKEY; RUN;
DATA COMBINED;
MERGE MATERIAL (IN=INA)
TYPE (IN=INB);
BY VPOBJKEY;
IF INA AND INB THEN OUTPUT COMBINED;
RUN;
```

Comment: I found out that It has to be sorted in order to merge correctly

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After you've done the rename in the set statement, MATERIAL contains a variable called VPOBJKEY, not a variable called VBELN. Try merging by VPOBJKEY instead.

Comment: thank you, this was useful, I did try it both ways and no luck, just forgot to change it